# MWAA Airflow no_status for some specific tasks

Tags: python, data-lake, mwaa

I am using MWAA aiflow 1.10 and the tasks do not start, even though the last ones are successful. I do not see any logs problem or anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why your Tasks wouldn't execute in the order you've told them via bitshift, unless you have set the [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/concepts.html#trigger-rules) away from `all_success` to `all_failed` for example. Especially if there's nothing in the logs, it implies that your `encrypt_to_stage` task has been set up to not execute if the previous tasks are successful.

A less likely possibility is that you've hit [this known issue](https://technical.thombedford.com/267), but I'd expect your results to be more random than what you've shared (unless there are other DAGs that are running in parallel that complete at the same time as these first two tasks).